# Nginx with PHP usage of SQLite throws error

Tags: php, docker, sqlite, nginx, alpine-linux

I'm using nginx in docker from `trafex/php-nginx`
But I don't get SQLite working.
The following php code

```
<?php
$db = new SQLite3('/var/private/anmeldungen.db');
$db->close();
```

throws this error `[error] 9#9: *33 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "SQLite3" not found in /var/www/html/phpinfo.php:3`

I'm using a dockerfile to install the sqlite package:

```
FROM trafex/php-nginx:latest

USER root
RUN apk add php8-pdo_sqlite

USER nobody
```

And in the PHPInfo I can see that the package is loaded:
[image: phpinfo part 1]
[image: phpinfo part 2]

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your package is wrong, PDO is PHP Data Object which is a higher layer designed to be able to work with any lower database protocol such as SQLite, MySQL, Postgres..., so implementing via PDO may help you a lot in long run if you would like to switch to another database without changing much (there may be some incompatible features but not much) of your source code.

To init a SQLite via PDO you have to do so:

```php
$dbh = new PDO('sqlite:/tmp/foo.db');
```

You can read more about that here https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.php.

If you want to stick with native SQLite (to use your SQLite3 class), you will have to install package `php8-sqlite3` but not the `php8-pdo_sqlite3`

```
apk add php8-sqlite3
```

This will work with your current code.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is included with PHP, you have to uncomment it in the php.ini file. But first you have to uninstall the one you installed because otherwise PHP will complain that there are two. I had the same problem, albeit not inside a Docker container. PHP agreed that SQLite was installed but the CLI wouldn't use it.

Comment: I removed the  `RUN apk add php8-pdo_sqlite` from the Dockerfile and recreated the container. And even after adding a config file in the /etc/php8/conf.d/ with this content: `extension=sqlite3.so
extension=pdo_sqlite.so` there is no SQLite support (also in the phpinfo the information about PDO drivers and SQLite Library is missing, but my config file is getting loaded)